# android webview not showing the web content completely

Tags: android

I have webview implementation in my application. Below is my webview activity code

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView homepageWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_URL);
        homepageWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.genericWebView);
        homepageWebView.setWebViewClient(new InstaPukkeiWebClient(WebViewActivity.this));
        WebSettings webSettings = homepageWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        homepageWebView.loadUrl(***url***);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        // If there is URL history then allowing to go back to those
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && homepageWebView.canGoBack()) {
            homepageWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If no webview history then restore default behavior
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

The value of ***url*** is 'http://www.nmlindia.nic.in'. The thing is that this site does open completely in my phone in browser but same is not happening in the webview of my application. Please help me out here. What I have to do to get the full view of the site?

Web content screenshot from my app 
[image]

Web content screenshot from my phone browser
[image]

You can see the tabs are not showing in the webview of my app.

Comment: Are you calling `webview.onPause();` in any activity? And are you Overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`?

Comment: i usually don't use webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); in my codes and it works perfectly for just try it

Comment: I really don't understand what is the problem. Can you give a screenshot between the 2 difference?

Comment: @Steven Hi i have added the screenshots to show the difference.

Comment: @Michal_196 I am overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and no call for `webview.onPause()`

Comment: Is your problem solved? I faced with similar issue